# sending packets to many hosts under the same router using java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

we are a group of kids in middle school trying to implement a program in java that going to be like a chat server under the network 
, we have one server outside the network and every client inside the network of the school 
we want to know how could we send 1 packet from the server to every client in the network because behind that router there are many computers(clients).

Comment: if there was a code the better, in order to get a proper answer here keep that in mind next time you ask and also take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have tow option here:

1. broadcasting
2. multicasting

I prefer `multicast` because it is more effective and doesn't disturb every computer in the network.

---

How Does It work?

Multicasting is the ability to broadcast a message to a group of listeners in a single transmission.

A good analogy of multicasting is radio, Thousands of people can tune in to a single broadcast event and listen to
the same message, Computers can do similar things when sending messages to listeners.

A group of client
machines can tune in to the same address and port number to receive a message that a server broadcasts
to that address and port.

The Java language provides multicasting functionality via datagram messaging.
Datagrams are independent, nonguaranteed messages that can be delivered over the network to clients.
(Being nonguaranteed means that the arrival, arrival time, and content are not predictable.) Unlike
messages sent over TCP, sending a datagram is a nonblocking event, and the sender is not notified of the
receipt of the message.

Datagrams are sent using the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) rather than TCP. The
ability to send multicast messages via UDP is one benefit over TCP, as long as the ordering, reliability, and
data integrity of the message are not mission-critical.

check [1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-broadcast-multicast) [2](https://www.developer.com/java/data/how-to-multicast-using-java-sockets.html) [3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) for more information about the topic